# How can I use a protocol's type in method signature?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a function like this:

```
// A generic function that can fetch values from the store given a type
// Corresponds to a table and it's rows
func fetch<T: FetchableRecord>(for theType: T.Type) -> [T] {
    // ... fetch from a store using the type
    // This compiles fine
}
```

How can I use this with a collection of types?

Ideally, if I have some conformers:

```
struct ModelA: FetchableRecord { }
struct ModelB: FetchableRecord { }
```

then I would like to be able to do:

```
let modelTypes: [FetchableRecord.Type] = [ModelA.self, ModelB.self]
modelTypes.forEach {
    fetch(for: $0) // xxx: does not compile: "Cannot invoke 'fetch' with an argument list of type '(for: FetchableRecord.Type)'"
}
```

At the very least, I would like to figure why this would not be possible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is `FetchableRecord.Type` is *not* the same as `ModelA.Type` or `ModelB.Type`. Even if both of the structs conform to `FetchableRecord` protocol, constraining the models (by conforming to a certain protocol) does not affect the "Types", more technically speaking:

`ModelA.self == FetchableRecord.self` OR `ModelB.self == FetchableRecord.self` is `false`.

In order to resolve this issue, you could implement the method's signiture as:

```
func fetch(for theType: FetchableRecord.Type) -> [FetchableRecord] {
    // ...
}
```

therefore, your code:

```
let modelTypes: [FetchableRecord.Type] = [ModelA.self, ModelB.self]
modelTypes.forEach {
    fetch(for: $0)
}
```

should work. At this point, you are dealing with it "Heterogeneously" instead of "Homogeneously".

Furthermore, if that makes it more sensible, note that when calling `fetch` method as per your implementation, it is:

[image]

the parameter type is `FetchableRecord.Protocol`. However, as per the above-mentioned implementation (in this answer), it is:

[image]

the parameter type is `FetchableRecord.Type`, which is the wanted result.